# React Native Flatlist inside Wrapper Component break the scolling

Tags: components, wrapper, flatlist

Hello i have a Problem with my wrapper component. If i put inside the Flatlist component the scrolling doesn't work anymore. I try to pur everywhere flex:1 (on flatlist, on the wrapper itself) but no changes still broken.

What is my mistake?

I expected the normal scroll behavior.

```
import React from 'react';
import { KeyboardAvoidingView, TouchableWithoutFeedback, Keyboard, Platform } from 'react-native';


const KeyboardAvoidingViewWrapper = ({ children, keyboardOffset }) => {
  const additionalOffset = Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 0 : 17;
  return (
    <KeyboardAvoidingView
      keyboardVerticalOffset={keyboardOffset ? keyboardOffset + additionalOffset : 65 + additionalOffset}
      behavior={Platform.OS == "ios" ? "padding" : "height"}
      style={{ flex: 1, }}
    >
      <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={Keyboard.dismiss}>
        {children}
      </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
    </KeyboardAvoidingView>
  )

}

export default KeyboardAvoidingViewWrapper;
```

In the Screen:

```
<KeyboardAvoidingViewWrapper>
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <FlatList
          data={data}
           .....
        />
</View>
</KeyboardAvoidingViewWrapper>
```

Any help is more than appreciate. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

try giving ***'position'*** to **behavior** property to your **KeyboardAvoidingView**.

```
<KeyboardAvoidingView behavior='position'>
```

Comment: When I insert this I do not see the content anymore. i add contentContainerStyle={{flex:1}}} and the content was visible again but I still cannot scroll